# How to find the third vertex of a triangle when lengths are unequal

Tags: geometry, triangulation

I have two vertices of a triangle and the lengths are unequal. How to find the third vertex?[image: Reference]

As the lengths are unequal, I dont know, how to proceed this. Whereas when the lengths are equal, I have solved the same when the lengths are equal for isosceles triangle.

I have come across https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration i.e., nD trilateration using non linear least square, Whereas I dont know how to proceed this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: The third vertex can be on either side of the line $d_2$ so you will have two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve the set of equations:
$$ (x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2 = d_1^2$$
$$ (x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2 = d_3^2$$
By subtracting one from another you get
$$ 2(x_3-x_2)x + 2(y_3-y_2)y + (x_2^2-x_3^2+y_2^2-y_3^2) = d_1^2 - d_3^2 $$
which allows you to find $y(x)$ as a linear function. Substitute it to one of the previous equations and you'll get a quadratic equation on $x$.

Comment: Could you tell me, how to handle this kind of expressions in python?

Comment: @MahamuthaM I don't know python unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Direct method, without solving equations:

Denote the vertices of the trianlge $V_1, \, V_2, \, V_3$ as show on your picture. You are given the coordinates of vertices  $V_1 = (x_2, y_2)$ and $V_2 = (x_3, y_3)$ as well as the lengths of the following side of the triangle $V_1V_2V_3$: 
$$d_1 = |V_1V_2| \,\, \text{ and } \,\, d_3 = |V_3V_1|$$

**Step 1:** Calculate the side length between vertices $2$ and $3$ 
$$d_2 = \sqrt{(x_3 - x_2)^2 + (y_3 - y_2)^2 \,}$$

**Step 2:** If we denote by $\theta_2 = \angle \, V_1V_2V_3$ the angle of the triangle at vertex $V_2$, then by the Law of Cosines:
$$d_3^2 = d_1^2 + d_2^2 - 2\,d_1 d_2\cos(\theta_2) $$   which can be transformed into
 $$d_1 \cos(\theta_2)  = \frac{d_1^2 + d_2^2  - d_3^2}{2\,d_2}$$
Denote by $H$ the orthogonal projection of vertex $V_1$ onto the side $V_2V_3$. Then $V_1H$ is the height of the triangle $V_1V_2V_3$, i.e. $V_1H \perp \, V_2V_3$ where $H \in V_2V_3$. Then triangle $V_1V_2H$ is right angled triangle and then
$$k = |V_2H| = d_1 \cos(\theta_2)  = \frac{d_1^2 + d_2^2  - d_3^2}{2\,d_2}$$

**Step 3:** By Pythagoras' theorem for the right angled triangle $V_1V_2H$
$$h = |V_1H| = \sqrt{|V_1V_2|^2 - |V_2H|^2} = \sqrt{d_1^2 - k^2}$$

**Step 4:** If $O$ is the origin of the coordinate system, then you are looking for
the position vector $\vec{OV_1}$ of point $V_1$, which is
$$\vec{OV_1} = \vec{OV_2} + \vec{V_2H} + \vec{HV_1}$$
By observing that vector $\vec{V_2V_3} \,\, || \,\, \vec{V_2H}$ and $\vec{V_2V_3} \, \perp \, \vec{HV_1}$ we can normalize it, rotated and rescale it to find:
\begin{align*}
&\vec{V_2H} = |V_2H|\left(\frac{1}{|V_2V_3|}\right) \vec{V_2V_3} = \left(\frac{k}{d_2}\right) \vec{V_2V_3} = \left(\frac{k}{d_2}\right) \begin{bmatrix} x_3 - x_2 \\ y_3 - y_2 \end{bmatrix}\\
&\vec{HV_1} = |HV_2|\left(\frac{1}{|V_2V_3|}\right) \big(\vec{V_2V_3}\big)^{\perp} = \left(\frac{h}{d_2}\right) \big(\vec{V_2V_3}\big)^{\perp} = \pm \left(\frac{h}{d_2}\right) \begin{bmatrix} y_2 - y_3 \\ x_3 - x_2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

And so we can calculate the coordinates of vertex $V_1 = (x_1, y_1)$: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix}\, = \,\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \, + \, \left(\frac{k}{d_2}\right) \begin{bmatrix} x_3 - x_2 \\ y_3 - y_2 \end{bmatrix} \,\pm\, \left(\frac{h}{d_2}\right) \begin{bmatrix} y_2 - y_3 \\ x_3 - x_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$ where
\begin{align*}
&d_2 = \sqrt{(x_3 - x_2)^2 + (y_3 - y_2)^2 \,}\\
&k = \frac{d_1^2 + d_2^2  - d_3^2}{2\,d_2} \\
&h = \sqrt{d_1^2 - k^2}
\end{align*}